# Why can't we free() memory that was allocated by new?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I know `free()` won't call the destructor, but what else will this cause besides that the member variable won't be destructed properly?

Also, what if we `delete` a pointer that is allocated by `malloc`?

Comment: If I borrow $1,000,000 (read: 1 MB) from you and then pay back someone else instead of you, would you get mad?

Same issue here, except now the recipient gets mad. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is implementation defined whether `new` uses `malloc` under the hood. Mixing `new` with `free` and `malloc` with `delete` [could cause a catastrophic failure at runtime if the code was ported to a new machine, a new compiler, or even a new version of the same compiler](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#mixing-malloc-and-delete).

Comment: Or even the same version of the same compiler but with compilation being done during a blue moon :-)

Comment: Or even the same compilation session, but in a different code unit. Or the same code unit. Or the same function. It's *undefined behaviour*, baby!

Comment: Is it really "implementation defined"? I would've guessed that it is **undefined**, which is very different from "implementation defined".

Comment: @JesperE: I never said that the behaviour (overall) was implementation defined. Its actually undefined. It is implementation defined whether new uses malloc and that's what I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Prasoon: So the compiler has to specify whether or not malloc uses new or not? That sounds odd.

Answer (score 9):

> I know free() won't call the destructor

And that is reason enough not to do it.

In addition, there's no requirement for a C++ implementation to even use the same memory areas for `malloc` and `new` so it may be that you're trying to free memory from a totally different arena, something which will almost certainly be fatal.

Comment: Best point. Only for plain old data one could consider it. But then why do it? +1!

Answer (score 4):

Many points:

- It's undefined behaviour, and hence inherently risky and subject to change or breakage at any time and for no reason at all.
- (As you know) `delete` calls the destructor and `free` doesn't... you may have some POD type and not care, but it's easy for someone else to add say a `string` to that type without realising there are weird limitations on its content.
- If you `malloc` and forget to use placement `new` to construct an object in it, then invoke a member function as if the object existed (including `delete` which calls the destructor), the member function may attempt operations using pointers with garbage values
- `new` and `malloc` may get memory from different heaps.
- Even **if** `new` calls `malloc` to get its memory, there may not be a 1:1 correspondence between the `new`/`delete` and underlying `malloc`/`free` behaviour.

  - e.g. `new` may have extra logic such as small-object optimisations that have proven beneficial to typical C++ programs but harmful to typical C programs.
- Someone may overload `new`, or link in a debug version of `malloc`/`realloc`/`free`, either of which could break if you're not using the functions properly.
- Tools like ValGrind, Purify and Insure won't be able to differentiate between the deliberately dubious and the accidentally.
- In the case of arrays, `delete[]` invokes all the destructors and `free()` won't, but also the heap memory typically has a counter of the array size (for 32-bit VC++2005 Release builds for example, the array size is in the 4 bytes immediately before the pointer value visibly returned by `new[]`.  This extra value may or may not be be there for POD types (not for VC++2005), but if it is `free()` certainly won't expect it.  Not all heap implementations allow you to free a pointer that's been shifted from the value returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

An important difference is that new and delete also call the constructor and destructor of the object. Thus, you may get unexpected behavior. That is the most important thing i think.

Answer (score 2):

Because it might not be the same allocator, which could lead to weird, unpredictable behaviour. Plus, you shouldn't be using malloc/free at all, and avoid using new/delete where it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the implementation -- it's possible to write an implementation where this actually works fine. But there's no guarantee that the pool of memory `new` allocates from is the same pool that `free()` wants to return the memory to. Imagine that both `malloc()` and `new` use a few bytes of extra memory at the beginning of each allocated block to specify how large the block is. Further, imagine that `malloc()` and `new` use different formats for this info -- for example, `malloc()` uses the number of bytes, but `new` uses the number of 4-byte long words (just an example). Now, if you allocate with `malloc()` and free with `delete`, the info `delete` expects won't be valid, and you'll end up with a corrupted heap.